# Browserify with paths to folders in my system

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

When I compile markdown-symbols using Browserify 3.30.2 (`browserify file.js -o bundle.js`), I get something like that :

```
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports...[function(_dereq_,module,exports){

},{}],2:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
...
...
[on line 8000] 
    : function (str, start, len) {
        if (start < 0) start = str.length + start;
        return str.substr(start, len);
    }
;

}).call(this,_dereq_("C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\process\\browser.js"))
},{"C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\process\\browser.js":11}],14:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
module.exports=_dereq_(3)
},{}],15:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
module.exports=_dereq_(4)
},{"./support/isBuffer":14,"C:\\Users\\ME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\process\\browser.js":11,"inherits":10}],16:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
var frep = _dereq_('frep');
var file = _dereq_('fs-utils');
var delims = _dereq_('delims');
var _ = _dereq_('lodash');
...
```

As you can see, there are absolute paths to my files here. Why ? How can I remove them ?

EDIT: here is my `build.js` file

```
 var browserify = require('browserify-middleware')
fs = require('fs');
var b = browserify('./index.js', {
    'opts.basedir': './'
});
b({
    // Mocks up express req and res
    headers: []
}, {
    getHeader: function () {},
    setHeader: function () {},
    send: function (a) {
        console.log('send', a);
    },
    end: function (a) {
        //console.log('end', a.constructor.name);
        //  fs.write('bundle.js', a, undefined, undefined, function (err) {
        console.log(a.toString());
        //});
        //  a.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bundle.js'));
    },

});
```

And to run `node build > bundle.js`. same problem. If I replace basedir value by for instancee `ihatebrowserify` there is an error about something not resolved.

Comment: What version of browserify are you using?

Comment: This is a bug in the `insert-module-globals` module. There is a pull request to fix it: https://github.com/substack/insert-module-globals/pull/31

Comment: @ssorallen thnal you very much!

Comment: @Vinz243, did you ever get this working (i.e., no local paths leaking into the browserified js)? It's over 5 months since you asked this question now, and I'm getting the exact same symptom, using the most recent versions of everything... :(

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did it otherwise

Answer (score 7):

This came across to me as well today. It turns out there's a boolean option `--full-path`[0] now that solves the problem.

For example:

```
browserify -o bundle.js --full-path=false index.js
```

[0] https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/bin/args.js

Comment: well this removes the absolute paths but now i get ```Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined``` at the top of my bundle.js ... :(

Comment: @Unispaw sounds like another problem. Did it appear only if you add `--full-path=false` switch?

Answer (score 5):

Almost 6 months later, and I've seen the same issue. Now I found a workaround that suited me, and others might benefit from it as well.

Google has given me this issue report: https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/issues/43 -- which reports this local system path disclosure on "browserify-shim", although it is a "browserify" issue from what I understood.

That issue suggests an workaround:

```
$ npm install -g intreq browser-pack browser-unpack
$ browserify example/main.js -t browserify-shim | browser-unpack | intreq | browser-pack
```

I've tested this and was satisfied with the results. However I wanted to go further, and integrate this into my Gruntfile.js. The solution I found, tested and that made me happy is to use [`unpathify`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/unpathify):

> Compress browserify require paths for better minification i.e. require('some/long/path') => require(1)

To use it, just install unpathify (`npm install --save-dev unpathify`) and add it to your build:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  browserify: {
    all: {
      files: {
        'build/all.js': ['some/file.js']
      }
    }
  },
  unpathify: {
    all: {
      src: ['build/all.js']
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Browserify resolves absolute path as default. If you do not want to see absolute paths, you can set `options.basedir` as you want. For example;

```
var browserify = require('browserify-middleware');
var b = browserify({'opts.basedir': './'});
```

Comment: What should I put in `your_path`? `C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\`? '\.` ? `markdown-symbols`? I put browserify in local modules.

Comment: Ah see, you have already stated base dir. However, I have answered your question before your edit.

Comment: @HüseyinBabel I don't really understand what you mean. Where did I stated base dir. In `build.js` on line 4 (`'opts.basedir': './'`) ?Wasn't it what you mean ? In `./index.js`? It i remove it, it doesn't work (exception). If I remove

Comment: In build.js, you have stated `opts.basedir` already. I said that, When I answer your question, There is no Edit section on your question

Comment: I don't understand. I put `var browserify = require('browserify-middleware'); var b = browserify({'opts.basedir': './'});`. I should remove `opts.basedir`?

Comment: You didn't get me. I have answered your question without knowing you have already used opts.basedir . After that you have edited your question, and you are already using opts.basedir. So my solution didn't work . After adding `opts.basedir': './'`, what is the new output about paths?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49067/discussion-between-vinz243-and-huseyin-babal)

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that somewhere, there are modules being included from absolute paths.

It doesn't happen to me when using browserify.

---

Actually it's more than a guess.

```
},{}],2:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
...
...
}).call(this,_dereq_("C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\process\\browser.js"))
},{"C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\process\\browser.js":11}],14:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
```

You have `_dereq_("C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\process\\browser.js")`; therefore, it must include that module.

If you set some Node global (no idea how on Windows) to look in `C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules`, you might not have to include the full path, but i can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks! I will search how to do it

Comment: You might also want to include the `process` package directly in your project. That should avoid the need for accessing the full path.

Comment: can it be related to sourcemaps ? https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/663

Comment: please, just to help me, can you tell me how to do it (changing node global) on other OS? (I do have Windows, sure, but just for help)

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if this is an answer to the original question, but I was having a similar problem. The bundled js file and the external sourcemap (using exorcist) being generated was containing absolute paths to folders on my system. After a headache figuring out why, it seems the culprit was babelify (previously 6to5ify). https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/663 & https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/19

The solution is simple though:

> browserify --debug -t [ babelify **--sourceMapRelative .** ]

or

> browserify({ debug: true })
>               .transform(babelify.configure({**sourceMapRelative: '.'** }))

Comment: Thanks but i didn't used babelify

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Browserify plugin available from the author of Browserify.  It's called [Bundle-Collapser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-collapser).  It'll replace folder paths with numerical indices.